# cannot convert from StringProperty to ObservableValue<SimpleStringProperty> java/javafx

Tags: java, javafx, properties, tablecolumn

I got the following error message in Java: "Cannot convert from `StringProperty` to `ObservableValue<SimpleStringProperty>`"

I am using a TableView and I want to add data in a TableColumn. I have three charts who all should contain one attribute of the class product (name, quantity, price).

I got the error in this line:

```
sname.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().
```

Relevant Code:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;

public class ViewShop extends BorderPane {

    private Button add;
    private Button remove;
    private TextField name;
    private TextField price;
    private TextField count;
    private VBox vbox;
    private HBox hbox;
    private TableView tv;
    private TableColumn<Product, SimpleDoubleProperty> sprice;
    private TableColumn<Product, SimpleStringProperty> sname;
    private TableColumn <Product, SimpleIntegerProperty>scount;
    private Label namelabel;
    private Label pricelabel;
    private Label countlabel;

    private ListView<fpt.com.Product> list; 

    public ViewShop()
    {

        remove=new Button("Remove");
        add=new Button("Add");
        name=new TextField();
        price=new TextField();
        count=new TextField();
        tv=new TableView<fpt.com.Product>();
        sprice=new TableColumn<>("Preis");
        sname= new TableColumn<>("Name");
        scount=new TableColumn<>("Anzahl");
        namelabel=new Label("Name");
        pricelabel=new Label("Preis");
        countlabel=new Label("Anzahl");
        tv.getColumns().addAll(sname,sprice,scount);
        hbox=new HBox();
        vbox=new VBox();
        list = new ListView<fpt.com.Product>();
//      
//       sname.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Product, SimpleStringProperty>, ObservableValue<SimpleStringProperty>>() {
//           public ObservableValue<SimpleStringProperty> call(CellDataFeatures<Product, SimpleStringProperty> p) {
//               // p.getValue() returns the Person instance for a particular TableView row
//               return  p.getValue().nameProperty();
//               
//                       }
//        });
        sname.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(remove, add);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(namelabel,name,pricelabel ,price, countlabel , count, hbox);
        this.setRight(vbox);
        this.setLeft(tv);
    }
    public void addEventHandleradd(EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler) {
        this.add.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, eventHandler);
    }
    public void addEventHandlerremove(EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler) {
        this.remove.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, eventHandler);
    }
    public String giveName()
    {
        return name.getText();
    }
    public String givePrice()
    {
        return price.getText();
    }
    public String giveCount()
    {
        return count.getText();
    }
    public ListView<fpt.com.Product> getList()
    {
        return list;
    }


}

import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;

public class Product implements fpt.com.Product {

    Long id;
    SimpleStringProperty name;
    SimpleIntegerProperty quantity;
    SimpleDoubleProperty price;

    public Product(String name, int quantity, double price)
    {
        this.name=new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.quantity=new SimpleIntegerProperty(quantity);
        this.price=new SimpleDoubleProperty(price);
    }




    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id=id;

    }

    @Override
    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price.set(price);
    }

    @Override
    public int getQuantity() {
        return this.quantity.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity.set(quantity);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    @Override
    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public DoubleProperty priceProperty() {
        return price;
    }

    @Override
    public IntegerProperty quantityProperty() {
        return quantity;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The types of your table columns are wrong. They should be

```
private TableColumn<Product, Number> sprice;
private TableColumn<Product, String> sname;
private TableColumn <Product, Number> scount;
```